# How to pass id attribute to controller's action in ASP.NET MVC project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-applications

I'm new to asp.net and would veery appreciate if someone could help me..
I have a form in my view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Projects", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = serviceId })) 
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Project</legend>

            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)     
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)       

            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)

            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description, new { rows = 20})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)

            <input type="submit" value="Save"  />

</fieldset>
}
```

`serviceId` i pass through ViewData (which is declared in the controller):

```
@{
    var serviceId = ViewData["serviceid"];
 }
```

Now on submitting i want to pass this `serviceId` to my `ActionResult` and inside this view i added script:

```
  $(function () {
    $("form").submit(function () {

        $.post("Projects/Edit", {Sid: $(this).attr('id'), }, function (data) {

        });
    });
});
```

and in my `Projects` controller, inside `Edit` ActionResult i get this id as a parameter:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Models.Project EditedProject, int Sid)
    {
        Models.DBProjects dbproject = new Models.DBProjects();
        PoleInvestProjectContext context = new PoleInvestProjectContext();
        UserAccount curUser = context.Users.Where(u => u.UserName ==    User.Identity.Name).First();
        EditedProject.UserId = curUser.UserId;

        EditedProject.ServiceId = Sid;
        dbproject.EditProject(EditedProject);

        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = Sid });
    }
```

Here is an `Error`:( When i try to submit the form:

```
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'Sid' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Edit(MyProject.Models.Project, Int32)' in 'MyProject.Controllers.ProjectsController'. 
An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
```

I would be soo grateful if someone could help!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have to post from JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a view model, ditch the javascript and the ViewData

```
public class EditViewModel()
{
  public string Title {get; set;}
  public string Description {get; set;}
  public int ServiceId {get; set;}
}
```

Set the ServiceId to the viewModel property instead of the ViewData
   object in the controller.

Strongly type your view to the viewModel instead of the entity
   object.

Then use a hidden field to pass the value back to the controller

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)     
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)       
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description, new { rows = 20})
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ServiceId)

<input type="submit" value="Save"  />
```

And change the signature of you post action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(EditViewModel viewModel)
{
  //...
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much! Looks so easy! So, each time i need to pass some Id i need to use hidden fields?

Comment: Glad to help. There are other ways, but this is the textbook 'mvc way'.  Whenever a question is some permutation of "How to pass x from view to controller", the answer is almost always "use a view model."